# going to a particular position with constant speed using accelStepper in arduino

Tags: arduino, acceleration, cnc

I've been trying to make a simple two axis cnc. I am just in the beginning phase to I just wanted to check out the accelStepper library. With the help of constantSpeed and Bounce sketch  example I got some idea and wrote the following code.

```
    #include <AccelStepper.h>
    AccelStepper stepperX(4, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    AccelStepper stepperY(4, 8, 9, 10, 11);
    unsigned int X = 800;
    unsigned int Y = 600;

    void setup(){
      stepperX.setMaxSpeed(200);
      stepperX.setSpeed(10);
      stepperY.setMaxSpeed(200);
      stepperY.setSpeed(10);
      stepperX.move(200);
      stepperY.move(200);
   }

   void loop(){
      stepperX.runSpeed();
      stepperY.runSpeed();
   }
```

When I upload this sketch the motor does not run.
But when I change runSpeed() to run() and add setAcceleration() the motor then runs but with acceleration. I don't want acceleration. So, is there any way to do this without acceleration.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs (the only difference between `move` and `moveTo` is that the former does a relative move):

> void AccelStepper::moveTo     (   long    absolute    )
>
> Set the target position. The run() function will try to move the motor
>   (at most one step per call) from the current position to the target
>   position set by the most recent call to this function. Caution:
>   moveTo() also recalculates the speed for the next step. If you are
>   trying to use constant speed movements, you should call setSpeed()
>   after calling moveTo().

Key line (as in pie): **If you are trying to use constant speed movements, you should call setSpeed() after calling moveTo().**

But having been there (making an XY plotter, 2 axis CNC), save yourself much grief and just use [grbl](https://github.com/grbl/grbl). It handles all the coordinated axis control, gcode parsing, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I get it i'll try it. And if it works I'll let you know, if it doesn't I'll shoot up more questions

Comment: The answer is incorrect. Using runSpeed you can't move to particular position. You shoud user runSpeedToPosition